# How can I write a Process to call --gen-key from GnuPG without the extra steps?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, gnupg, system.diagnostics

I am trying to create a custom wrapper for GnuPG.

I've doing fine so far for very basic `gpg` commands such as `--list-keys`, `--version` etc.

But for some that require extra steps I can't figure out how to work it out, like for `--gen-key`, there are several steps from choosing the encryption algorithm to e-mail of the key-pair owner how can I accomplish that using `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Here is a simple code from a current one that already works.

```
    protected const string GpgExe = "gpg";

    protected Process GetProcess(string arguments)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = GpgExe,
            Arguments = arguments,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true
        };

        Process process = new Process { StartInfo = info };
        return process;
    }

    public string GetVersion()
    {
        string version = "";

        string arguments = "--version";

        using (var process = this.GetProcess(arguments))
        {
            process.Start();
            version = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            process.Close();
        }

        return version;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to program against an interactive prompt (which should be possible through parsing GnuPG's stdout and subsequently providing the matching input), use [GnuPG's unattended key generation capabilities](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html) provided for such cases.

The linked documentation page provides a small example, showcasing the rather easy to understand syntax:

```
$ cat >foo <<EOF
     %echo Generating a basic OpenPGP key
     Key-Type: DSA
     Key-Length: 1024
     Subkey-Type: ELG-E
     Subkey-Length: 1024
     Name-Real: Joe Tester
     Name-Comment: with stupid passphrase
     Name-Email: joe@foo.bar
     Expire-Date: 0
     Passphrase: abc
     %pubring foo.pub
     %secring foo.sec
     # Do a commit here, so that we can later print "done" :-)
     %commit
     %echo done
EOF
$ gpg2 --batch --gen-key foo
 [...]
$ gpg2 --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring ./foo.sec \
       --keyring ./foo.pub --list-secret-keys
/home/wk/work/gnupg-stable/scratch/foo.sec
------------------------------------------
sec  1024D/915A878D 2000-03-09 Joe Tester (with stupid passphrase) <joe@foo.bar>
ssb  1024g/8F70E2C0 2000-03-09
```